# Relative file path within a compiled EXE

Tags: python, copy, executable, relative-path, shutil

I have been looking everywhere for this answer but no luck.

Here is what I am trying todo. I have a compiled python executable that has several directories. Within these directories, I have my functions, and files that I want to copy from the .exe to the desktop. Here is what the file structure of the executable looks like for the purpose of this post:

```
EXECUTABLE.exe
|
+--configurations/
|    |
|    +--Win_Mozilla/
|        |
|        +--Extensions/ # Directory I want to copy
|        +--Firefox/ # Directory I want to copy
|        +--SystemExtensionDev/ # Directory I want to copy
|
+--functions/
     |
     +--runfunction.py
```

What I need to happen is have the runfunction.py copy the files from configurations/Win_Mozilla/ into a different folder in %appdata%. To make this happen I have the following in runfunction.py:

```
import shutil

print('Configuring browser...')
try:
    shutil.rmtree(r'%appdata%\Mozilla\Extensions')
    shutil.rmtree(r'%appdata%\Mozilla\Firefox')
    shutil.rmtree(r'%appdata%\Mozilla\SystemExtensionsDev')
except Exception as e:
    print('Error caught: ' + str(e))
shutil.copytree('../configurations/Win_Mozilla/Extensions', # Error occurs here
                r'%appdata%\Mozilla\Extensions')
shutil.copytree('../configurations/Win_Mozilla/Firefox',
                r'%appdata%\Mozilla\Firefox')
shutil.copytree('../configurations/Win_Mozilla/SystemExtensionsDev',
                r'%appdata%\Mozilla\SystemExtensionsDev')
print('Firefox has been configured')
```

When this is run, I get thrown an error saying `file path '../configurations/Win_Mozilla/Extensions' cannot be found` leaving me to believe that shutil is having a problem with relative paths. I can't have the path hardcoded in due to it being a compiled program.

**Just to be clear, I am trying to copy a folder within an already compiled executable, out onto the Desktop or some other location**

Right?

Can someone please help me out with this? Am I doing something wrong, syntax errors, or is this just not possible what I am trying to do? Would I be better off just having the program shipped with the configuration files separate?

Also, I have been staring at the docs for [shutil](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html?highlight=shutil#module-shutil) for a long time to see if I was just being dumb and forgot to add something or if it said anything about if having to absolute paths, but I didn't see anything.

Any help with this problem is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct slashes for the paths? Your first arguments in copytree uses forward slashes whereas the second ones uses backslashes. What happens when you make all the slashes forward slashes or all of them backward slashes?

Answer (score 1):

**Will This Solve Your Problem?**

```py
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))  # To Get A Relative File Path On Any OS(Windows, Mac, Linux)
print(BASE_DIR)
```